# Why does it not accept it as an array and keeps saying that it resolves to Class<Character>?

Tags: java, arrays, class, character, resolve

I think it's pretty ovious what I tried to establish, an array of vowels and consonants, but that error drives me almost mad. I hope someone can explain me my mistake. Thanks in advance;)

```
public static int dez = 97;


public char[] setConsonantArray(){

    char[] consonant = new char[21];

    int indexCounter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i>27; i++){
        if(dez != 97 && dez != 101 && dez != 105 && dez != 111 && dez !=117){
            char[indexCounter] = (char) dez;
            indexCounter++;
        }else{
        }
        dez++;
    }
    return consonant;
}



public char[] setVowelArray(){

    char[] vowel = new char[5];

    int indexCounter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i>27; i++){
        if(dez == 97 || dez == 101 || dez == 105 || dez == 111 || dez ==117){
            char[indexCounter] = (char) dez;
            indexCounter++;
        }else{}
        dez++;
    }
    return vowel;
}
```

}

Comment: Also maybe good to know, that error shows up on the lines where I used 
char[indexCounter] = (char) dez;

Comment: You don't (and can't) have a variable named `char`.  You probably meant to write `consonant[indexCounter]` and `vowel[indexCounter]`.  (Also, you need to use `i < 27` in your loop, not `i > 27`.)

Comment: Thank you so much!!
It was a stupid mistake lol^^